# Using Tidyverse to Rank the last X values in a Tibble

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to rank values in a tibble by group (target in the example below). However, I'd like to specify a rank for only the last 10 values. For example, once I get to the 15th value, I'd like to provide the ranking of that value based on values 5-15.

```
set.seed(123)

tib <- tibble(
  target = c(rep(1, 20), rep(2, 20)),
  session = rep(1:20, 2),
  value = runif(n = 40, min = 40, max = 100)
)
```

In the example above I have two targets that each were run across 20 sessions. Each target produces a value in each session. That value should be ranked relative to the values in the previous 10 sessions.

How would I do this using tidyverse functions?

I have not been able to figure out a solution to this problem yet. I have considered using one of the various ranking functions (e.g., row_number, min_rank, dense_rank, ntile, or percent_rank), but cannot figure out how to specify the look back window.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a rolling-window thing. I'll demo using `zoo::rollapply`.

```r
library(dplyr)
tib |>
  group_by(target) %>%
  mutate(
    rank_last_10 = zoo::rollapplyr(value, 10, partial = TRUE,
                                   FUN = function(z) rank(z)[length(z)])
  ) |>
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 40 × 4
#    target session value rank_last_10
#     <dbl>   <int> <dbl>        <dbl>
#  1      1       1  57.3            1
#  2      1       2  87.3            2
#  3      1       3  64.5            2
#  4      1       4  93.0            4
#  5      1       5  96.4            5
#  6      1       6  42.7            1
#  7      1       7  71.7            4
#  8      1       8  93.5            7
#  9      1       9  73.1            5
# 10      1      10  67.4            4
# # ℹ 30 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

---

Data

```r
tib <- structure(list(target = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), session = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), value = c(57.2546512074769, 87.2983081266284, 64.538615308702, 92.9810442402959, 96.4280370576307, 42.7333899633959, 71.6863292828202, 93.5451426636428, 73.0861008679494,  67.3968841182068, 97.4100007209927, 67.2000493714586, 80.654238127172, 74.3580041173846, 46.175480959937, 93.9894982241094, 54.7652640612796, 42.5235720118508, 59.6752431569621, 97.2702189488336, 93.3723589638248, 81.568204369396, 78.4304088260978, 99.6561865974218, 79.3423479469493, 82.5118280900642, 72.6439614826813, 75.6485212268308, 57.3495842376724, 48.8268188387156, 97.7814539521933, 94.1379427071661, 81.442316705361, 87.7280450612307, 41.476821070537, 68.6677582655102, 85.507572251372, 52.9844761500135,  59.0908604580909, 53.8975471211597)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -40L))
```